# How to pass multiple interface parameters in a web API Controller contructor if I am using Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I'm using dependency Injection to call my objects, so is there a neater way of adding more parameters in the constructor without making the constuctor signature long just like my case below?

```
   public ObjectController(IParam1 param1, IParam2 param2, IParam3 param3, 
   IParam4 param4,IParam5 param6,IParam7 param8)
    {
        _param1= param1;
        _param2 = param2;
        _param3= param3;
        _param4= param4;
        _param5= param5;
        _param6= param6;
        _param7= param7;
        _param8= param8;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, I don't think there's another way to do it. But, generally speaking, a large number of dependencies for a single class probably means you need to rethink your design.

Comment: No, but that's a possible indication that your controller has too many responsibilities

Comment: If I had a couple of objects linked to the controller, what is the best way or design to handle it or to break it down to avoid having many parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, your controller has too much responsibility. I would recommend you break your functionality into Services/Business Logic services.

```
public class UserService : IUserService {
    
    IParam _param;
    IParam2 _param2;
    
    public UserService(IParam param, IParam2 param2) {
        _param = param;
        _param2 = param2;
    }
}


public class LoginService : ILoginService {
    
    IParam _param;
    IParam2 _param2;
    
    public UserService(IParam param, IParam2 param2) {
        _param = param;
        _param2 = param2;
    }
}
```

Then you can inject it into your controller

```
public Controller(IUserService userService, ILoginService loginService) { ... }
```

And if it it still too much I would recommend spliting your controller as well.

Comment: This is a known refactoring named [Facade Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).